# What is a recommended Android utility class collection?

Tags: android, android-widget

I often find myself writing very similar code across projects. And more often than not, I copy stuff over from old projects.

Things like:

- Create images with round corners
- read density into a static variable & re-use. 4 lines..
- disable / hide multiple views / remote views at once. Example:

}

```
public static void disableViews(RemoteViews views, int... ids) {
    for (int id : ids) {
        views.setInt(id, SET_VISIBILITY, View.GONE);
    }
}

public static void showViews(RemoteViews views, int... ids) {
    for (int id : ids) {
        views.setInt(id, SET_VISIBILITY, View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I'd love to package these kind of functions into 1 letter / 2 letter class names, i.e. `V.showViews(RemoteViews views, int... ids)` would be easy to write & remember I hope.

I'm searching for Github recommendations, links and if nothing is found, I perhaps will start a small project on github to collect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu, it might be worth to study and eventually extend it. It's a utility framework not only for views but covering other aspects as well.